# PHP 500 Error after 1 hour of execution

Tags: php, mysql, logging

I have a PHP code which does the below

1) Select query to read from DB

2) Loop through the results ( I got like 150K Rows)

3) Do some processing on the each sql row and log this to file using  file_put_contents (Append mode, no file opening/closing)

But after like 1 hour of execution, the code throws a 500 error (On Chrome) with a message saying server cant handle the request.

There was nothing echoed on the screen or  PHP error log.

NOTE: - When I look at the log file I see like 35000 lines on the log, it means it is processing like 35K records and then failing.

Comment: Post the backtrace.

Comment: Jobs that run for an hour should not be running in the browser

Comment: This is likely because PHP is running out of memory if I were to take a guess.

Comment: @jpic I am not sure how I can get the back trace, if you can give me some link on that, I will surely post that one for you.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am testing the code on my system and they will run this on a separate server . I need to make sure it runs fine on my system first.

Comment: @bugfroggy Not really, if that was a memory issue, it will log in the error saying something like "tried to allocate XXX bytes but only got ZZZ " ( I have faced this issue many times before on my system)

Comment: I think you need the xdebug ext in PHP to have a backtrace, could you post your server logs too ?

Comment: @jpic I do have the xdebug on php but the errors are turned off for that, but the server logs was blank. Will enable that one and run again and post here.